# DataSnapshot is full and empty at the same time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with Android Studio trying to use the Firebase Database.
I'm running into the following problem.
I want to create cards for multiple dinosaurs (these are in the Db).
so what i tried is using the "onChildAdded" function provided by Firebase.
Using a DataSnapshot i am trying to only add cards of dinosaurs that have not been "rated" yet by the user. (See it like a tinder app where people can like or dislike dinosaurs).

Here is my code:

```
public int counter = 0;
    private void getDinos() {
        final DatabaseReference dinosDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Dinos");
        dinosDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    ArrayList<String> dinoList = new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("Allosaurus"); add("Ankylosaurus"); add("Baryonyx");add("Brachiosaurus");add("Carnotaurus");add("Dilophosaurus");add("Diplodocus");add("Gallimimus");  add("Giganotosaurus"); add("Iguanodon"); add("Megalosaurus"); add("Spinosaurus"); add("Stegosaurus"); add("Triceratops"); add("Tyrannosaurus"); add("Velociraptor");}};
                    if (!dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(i)).child("connections").child("like").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(i)).child("connections").child("dislike").hasChild(currentUId)) {
                        Log.d("mine", "" + dataSnapshot + dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(counter)).child("connections").child("dislike").hasChild(currentUId));//deze shit gaat dus fout
                        cards theItem = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), (String) dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(i)).getKey());
                        rowItems.add(theItem);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

As you can see i have a Log.d line on line 10 that logs the current dataSnapshot and right after if the current user has disliked that dinosaur.

The first part of that log line correctly shows the dataSnapshot but the second part is always false for some reason.
Below are the Logs of one run.

```
06-19 19:48:07.602 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening 

D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Allosaurus, value = {dummy=Allosaurus, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.604 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Ankylosaurus, value = {dummy=Ankylosaurus, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
    DataSnapshot { key = Baryonyx, value = {dummy=Baryonyx, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.605 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Brachiosaurus, value = {dummy=Brachiosaurus, connections={like={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}, dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.606 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Carnotaurus, value = {dummy=Carnotaurus, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.607 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Dilophosaurus, value = {dummy=Dilophosaurus, connections={like={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.609 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Diplodocus, value = {dummy=Diplodocus, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.610 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Gallimimus, value = {dummy=Gallimimus} }false
    DataSnapshot { key = Giganotosaurus, value = {dummy=Giganotosaurus} }false
    DataSnapshot { key = Iguanodon, value = {dummy=Iguanodon} }false
06-19 19:48:07.611 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Megalosaurus, value = {dummy=Megalosaurus} }false
    DataSnapshot { key = Spinosaurus, value = {dummy=Spinosaurus, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.612 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Stegosaurus, value = {dummy=Stegosaurus} }false
06-19 19:48:07.613 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Triceratops, value = {dummy=Triceratops} }false
    DataSnapshot { key = Tyrannosaurus, value = {dummy=Tyrannosaurus, connections={like={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
06-19 19:48:07.615 9671-9671/com.example.baksteen_13.dinopackopening D/mine: DataSnapshot { key = Velociraptor, value = {dummy=Velociraptor, connections={dislike={eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2=eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2}}} }false
```

As you can see most dinosaurs have already been rated but the true/false output is always false.

Lastly here is a part of my Database:

```
    {
  "Users" : {
    "Dinos" : {
      "Allosaurus" : {
        "connections" : {
          "dislike" : {
            "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2" : "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2"
          }
        },
        "dummy" : "Allosaurus"
      },
      "Ankylosaurus" : {
        "connections" : {
          "dislike" : {
            "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2" : "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2"
          }
        },
        "dummy" : "Ankylosaurus"
      },
      "Baryonyx" : {
        "connections" : {
          "dislike" : {
            "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2" : "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2"
          }
        },
        "dummy" : "Baryonyx"
      },
      "Brachiosaurus" : {
        "connections" : {
          "dislike" : {
            "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2" : "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2"
          },
          "like" : {
            "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2" : "eSUnb0kHS1eZByRpZyeRi9SrSfe2"
          }
        },
        "dummy" : "Brachiosaurus"
      }
    },
    "Human" : {
      "1ngP9WzFw9MZU6AiGVgo08orpvA3" : {
        "name" : "klaas"
      },
      "5O2eVDdQs6eAYCykNorMzGd66Ys2" : {
        "name" : "jetske"
      },
      "AGGUm2y3OAQzJJWEmFXkPPJVsS23" : {
        "name" : "johan"
      }
    }
  },
  "message" : "Hello, World!"
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some insight on what i am doing wrong here. I'm really new to Android Studio and this is only a school project so it doesn't matter if the solution is a really bad one. If it works it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I have to use an answer but:

It looks like you aren't iterating through all of the nodes within the DataSnapshot, so you are only getting whatever the value of the dataSnapshot parameter is. You aren't iterating deep enough into the tree.

You need a foreach loop to iterate through the dataSnapshot's children nodes.

Try this and set a breakpoint at the foreach loop and debug the app and see what values are represented as the keys and values. I can't really help much more without having the actual app to play with but I feel like this should help:

```
  public int counter = 0;

  private void getDinos() {
  final DatabaseReference dinosDb = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Dinos");
  dinosDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable 
 String s) {

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
      ArrayList<String> dinoList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Allosaurus");
        add("Ankylosaurus");
        add("Baryonyx");
        add("Brachiosaurus");
        add("Carnotaurus");
        add("Dilophosaurus");
        add("Diplodocus");
        add("Gallimimus");
        add("Giganotosaurus");
        add("Iguanodon");
        add("Megalosaurus");
        add("Spinosaurus");
        add("Stegosaurus");
        add("Triceratops");
        add("Tyrannosaurus");
        add("Velociraptor");
      }};
      if (!dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(i)).child("connections").child("like").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(i)).child("connections").child("dislike").hasChild(currentUId)) {
        Log.d("mine", "" + dataSnapshot + dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(counter)).child("connections").child("dislike").hasChild(currentUId));//deze shit gaat dus fout
        cards theItem = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), (String) dataSnapshot.child(dinoList.get(i)).getKey());
        rowItems.add(theItem);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    }
      counter++;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

}

Comment: Awesome, happy to help! Realtime Database is awesome. Firebase in general is a great tool.

Comment: i totally agree!